# How to convert an special hex character from an html page in bash?

Tags: bash, ascii, hex

I have a script which process some information coming from a web page. I guess that because of the encoding of the page, some special characters are encoded in hexadecimal.
For example, I have the the string "%2f" that should be translated to "/".

How can I, in bash, translate those special characters in hex to ASCII?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash has a `printf` builtin, which can around the same as we could learn in C. The syntax a little bit differs.

`printf '\x2f'`

If you don't need to worry about higher-level data consistency problems, you can simply convert an url by this function:

```
function deUrl() {
    printf "${1//%/\\x}"
}
```

(It converts every `%` to a `\x`, then prints it with printf.)

Answer (score 4):

Such entities can be decoded with this python one-liner:

```
$ python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1])"  "%2f"
/
```

The code is not limited to single characters.  It will accept more complex strings:

```
$ python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1])"  "%2d and %2f"
- and /
```

Python's `urllib.unquote` is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote).

Comment: Thanks! I will look at it as soon as I have time to play with python :)